# Error en consulta de actualización en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Buenas tardes. Estoy intentando enviar una consulta de actualización pero no se realiza, la página del formulario es esta:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
{
header('Location:auth');
exit();
}
include 'conexion.php';
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
//Consulta numero de mensajes
$grupo= $_GET['grupo'];
$iii="1";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Software Benedicto XVI | Software Eclesiástico SisPasIn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/FancyZoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/FancyZoomHTML.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#seminaristas').DataTable();
                rowReorder: true
        } );
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#mensajes').DataTable();
                rowReorder: true
        } );
    </script>

<body onLoad="setupZoom()">

<div class="container">
<center><h1> <font face="Trajan Pro">Resultados</font></h1></center>
<a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> Regresar</button></a></br></br>

<form method="post" name="actualizar" id="actualizar" action="actualizar.php">
    <table id="seminaristas" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellidos, Nombre</th>
            <?php
              $sentencia=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
              While($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia)){
            ?>
                  <th><?php echo $resultado['nombre_calificacion']; ?> (<?php echo $resultado['porcentaje']; ?>%)</th>
            <?php } ?>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellidos, Nombre</th>
            <?php
              $sentencia=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
              $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia);
              While($resultado=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia)){
            ?>
                  <th><?php echo $resultado['nombre_calificacion']; ?> (<?php echo $resultado['porcentaje']; ?>%)</th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php //carga los nombres
            $ss=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM seminaristas JOIN grupo_estudiante WHERE grupo_estudiante.Idg='$grupo' AND grupo_estudiante.Id=seminaristas.Id ORDER BY seminaristas.apellido, seminaristas.nombre ASC");
    $ii="1";
    While($rr=mysqli_fetch_array($ss)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rr['apellido']; ?>, <?php echo $rr['nombre']; ?></td>

    <?php
      $sentencia2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
      $i="1";
      While($resultado2=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2)){

        $numero_cali=$resultado2['Idcal'];
      $estudiante=$rr['Id'];

        $sentencia3=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM notas WHERE calificacion='$numero_cali' AND estudiante='$estudiante' AND grupo='$grupo'");
        $resultado3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sentencia3);
      ?>

<td><input name="nota<?php echo $i; ?>[]" data-id="<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" id="nota<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" value="<?php echo $resultado3['nota']; ?>" /> <input data-id="<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" id="porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $resultado2['porcentaje']; ?>" /> <input name="idnota<?php echo $i; ?>[]" id="idnota<?php echo $i; ?>-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" style="display:none" value="<?php echo $resultado3['Idn']; ?>" /></td>
<td hidden><input name="idn[]" id="<?php echo $iii; ?>" value="<?php echo $iii; ?>" /></td>
<td hidden><input name="grupo" id="grupo" value="<?php echo $grupo; ?>" /></td>

<?php $i++; $iii++; } ?>

<td><input name="resultado[]" id="resultado-<?php echo $estudiante; ?>" value="0" readonly /></td>
<?php $ii++; } ?>
        </tr>
</table>

</th>

<input type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-info col-md-offset-9" />
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input').click(function() {
$(this).select();
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#actualizar").find(':input').each(function() {
var elemento= this;
var dataid = $(this).data('id');

<?php
  $sentencia2=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
  $i="1";
  While($resultado2=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia2)){
  ?>
  var nota<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#nota<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
  var porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
<?php $i++; } ?>

var resultado = <?php  $sentencia22=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
$i="1";
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia22);
While($resultado22=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia22)){
?>(nota<?php echo $i; ?>*porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>/100) <?php if ($i < $numero) {  echo "+"; } else { echo ""; } ?> <?php $i++; } ?>

$('#resultado-' + dataid).val(resultado);
});
});

$('input').keyup(function() {
var dataid = $(this).data('id');

<?php
  $sentencia23=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
  $i="1";
  While($resultado23=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23)){
  ?>
  var nota<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#nota<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
  var porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?> = parseFloat($('#porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>-' + dataid).val());
<?php $i++; } ?>

var resultado = <?php  $sentencia22=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'");
$i="1";
$numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia22);
While($resultado22=mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia22)){
?>(nota<?php echo $i; ?>*porcentaje<?php echo $i; ?>/100) <?php if ($i < $numero) {  echo "+"; } else { echo ""; } ?> <?php $i++; } ?>

$('#resultado-' + dataid).val(resultado);
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el código de la página actualizar que se supone debería hacer la consulta de actualización a la base de datos pero no ocurre.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$grupo= $_POST['grupo'];

$i="1";
if(isset($nota[$i]))
{
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($_POST['idn']); $i++)
    {
        $sentencia23=mysqli_query(
            $conexion,
            "SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE grupo='$grupo'"
        );
        $numero = mysqli_num_rows($sentencia23);

        $ii='1';
        $nota='nota';
        $idnota='idnota';


        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE notas SET nota = ? WHERE Idn = ?");

        while ($resultado23 = mysqli_fetch_array($sentencia23))
        {
            ${$nota.''.$ii}   = $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i];
            ${$idnota.''.$ii} = $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i];

            //$result = $conexion->query(
            //  "UPDATE notas SET nota = \'$nota.''.$ii\' WHERE Idn = \''$idnota.''.$ii'\'"
            //);
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'ss',
                $_POST[$nota.''.$ii][$i],
                $_POST[$idnota.''.$ii][$i]
            );

            $stmt->execute();
            $ii++;
        }
    }
}

//Comprobación de la actualización
$res = ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
    ? "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente."
    : "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización."
        . $ejecucion->error;
/*
//Comprobación de la actualización
if ($resultado = $conexion->query($stmt))
{
    $res = "Los datos han sido actualizados satisfactoriamente.";
}
else 
{
    $res = "Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización." . $ejecucion->error;
}
*/

mysqli_close($conexion);
echo $res;
?>

</html>
```

Los errores que aparecen son:

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 49
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 49
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ejecucion in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 52
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\seminario\academia\actualizar.php on line 52
>
> Intente nuevamente, no se ha podido ejecutar la actualización.

¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo puedo organizar?

Comment: $result = $conexion->query(
            "UPDATE notas SET nota = \'$nota.''.$ii\' WHERE Idn = \''$idnota.''.$ii'\'"
            ); 
¿Así estará bien?

Comment: ese query copialo y pegalo en mysql en tabla que vas a modificar solo cambia los valores $nota y $idnota pon los valores que esta ingresando desde tu formulario y ve si te funciona

Comment: El problema es que los valores vienen en un array... ¿Cómo lo hago?, vistes como mando los datos y genero la consulta de actualización?

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil la consulta es correcta, se llaman **consultas preparadas** y es así como deben escribirse para no poner en riesgo la seguridad de los datos y de todo el sistema. Lo que no se debe hacer es precisamente lo que estás recomendando hacer. Sugiero que investigues sobre lo que es la Inyección SQL.

Comment: A. Cedano, ¿Qué sugerencia me da usted para solucionar este problema que se me está presentando? Gracias!

Comment: Para empezar: `$ejecucion` no lo defines en ninguna parte y menos va a tener propiedades de objeto (eso explica los dos últimos E_NOTICE).  `mysqli_query` espera un string como parámetro. Le estás pasando un objeto `mysqli_stmt`, por eso reclama que es `empty query`. Finalmente, si `$nota['1']` no está definido (y no veo que lo esté), el script no entra al bucle y nunca llegas a definir `$stmt`, por lo que no está definida esa variable más abajo, lo cual explica el primer error. **Te recomiendo** que hagas un `var_dump` a todo lo que te lleva por `$_POST` porque tantos índices resulta confuso

Comment: No sé porque no está recibiendo el Array la página actualizar... Cómo organizarlo?